# MySQL #1054 - Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge two MySQL statements, I think I'm close to solving this but I get **"#1054 - Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'"** referring to the bold text below.

I've tried encompassing the **lat** and **lng** text with "", '' and even `` to no effect.

```
SELECT post_attributes_3.value AS name, clean, post_attributes.value AS lat, post_attributes_1.value AS lng, post_attributes_2.value AS category, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( **lat** ) ) * cos( radians( **lng** ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( **lat** ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM post_attributes AS post_attributes_3 INNER JOIN ((post_attributes AS post_attributes_1 INNER JOIN (posts INNER JOIN post_attributes ON posts.id = post_attributes.post_id) ON post_attributes_1.post_id = posts.id) INNER JOIN post_attributes AS post_attributes_2 ON posts.id = post_attributes_2.post_id) ON post_attributes_3.post_id = posts.id
WHERE (((post_attributes_3.name)="name") AND ((post_attributes_2.name)="category_id") AND ((post_attributes.name)="lat") AND ((post_attributes_1.name)="lng"))
HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

The two SQL statements I have combined below:

```
SELECT name, clean, lat, lng, category, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM categorize HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

and

```
SELECT post_attributes_3.value AS name, clean, post_attributes.value AS lat, post_attributes_1.value AS lng, post_attributes_2.value AS category
FROM post_attributes AS post_attributes_3 INNER JOIN ((post_attributes AS post_attributes_1 INNER JOIN (posts INNER JOIN post_attributes ON posts.id = post_attributes.post_id) ON post_attributes_1.post_id = posts.id) INNER JOIN post_attributes AS post_attributes_2 ON posts.id = post_attributes_2.post_id) ON post_attributes_3.post_id = posts.id
WHERE (((post_attributes_3.name)="name") AND ((post_attributes_2.name)="category_id") AND ((post_attributes.name)="lat") AND ((post_attributes_1.name)="lng"));
```

These two MySQL statements are fine separately however it may be something to do with the use of the AS statement.

**UPDATE: Thanks for your help guys, but because of the way this select query was being used I've opted to create a MySQL view and use that to run a similar SQL command to my first one.**

Comment: DESCRIBE post_attributes ?  DESCRIBE categorize ?  Ensure you have aliases for all table references.    Try with alias name prefix `post_attributes_2.lat` MySQL might need to know exactly which table row you want 'lat' from.

Comment: post_attributes table contains post_id, name and value, this table is used to store different types of information about a post, one of these is a lat and lng value.
category table contains id and name.

Comment: Someone answered since along same lines. Introduce a table alias for `categorize AS cat` then every column reference you copied from middle SQL like `name` replace with `cat.name` this would include `cat.lat`.  Table aliases are needed to disambiguate which data you are referring to when there maybe multiple columns called `lng` in play.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the aliases by the real column names:

```
SELECT post_attributes_3.value AS name, clean, post_attributes.value AS lat, post_attributes_1.value AS lng, post_attributes_2.value AS category, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( post_attributes.value ) ) * cos( radians( post_attributes_1.value ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( post_attributes.value ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM post_attributes AS post_attributes_3 INNER JOIN ((post_attributes AS post_attributes_1 INNER JOIN (posts INNER JOIN post_attributes ON posts.id = post_attributes.post_id) ON post_attributes_1.post_id = posts.id) INNER JOIN post_attributes AS post_attributes_2 ON posts.id = post_attributes_2.post_id) ON post_attributes_3.post_id = posts.id
WHERE (((post_attributes_3.name)="name") AND ((post_attributes_2.name)="category_id") AND ((post_attributes.name)="lat") AND ((post_attributes_1.name)="lng"))
HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

## [SQL fiddle to show how to use `WHERE` and `HAVING` with column aliases](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7c96/5)

The last query causes an error, this is the problem you are having too.

Comment: Thanks Jocelyn, it's not returning any errors, hopefully this is it.

Comment: I still can't seem to get any data from the database, the following link is using the first SQL statement.
http://www.local-social.co.uk/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=54&lng=-1.57&radius=2500000
I altered the select command in this new file but it's not returning anything:
http://www.local-social.co.uk/phpsqlsearch-xml.php?lat=54&lng=-1.57&radius=2500000